# A Smashy Riddle

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> Consisting of 2 different personalities,
>
> You may not want to get near me
>
> A genius doctor in one; A huge mysterious creature in the other
>
> Some may be terrified just by the sight of me
>
> But I can actually be your savior
>
> Though you should still be careful
>
> Don't ever try to upset me
>
> Because that will be the one thing you regret doing in your life

Note :

> As always, the title is also a **hint** :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it

> Dr Robert Bruce Banner (Hulk)?

Explanation:

> After Dr Robert Bruce Banner had an accidental exposure to gamma rays, he is transformed into Hulk, big green-skinned and muscular humanoid, whenever he gets angry. Often he goes on destructive rampages, and this is why you wouldn't want to be near him and would be terrified of him when he is angry. But whenever Bruce is able to control Hulk, he saves people from villains.

Comment: Dang it! I thought I made this one hard enough :D Btw, give explanations

Comment: @KevinL Added the explanation! For me it was quite easy, but I like comics a lot... maybe the title was too big of a give away..? btw +1 for this one, and I can't wait for a new (comics-related) one! :D

Comment: Thanks and congrats. Will probably try to make a new one (If possible). Btw, gonna wait for a while before accepting ur answer :D

Comment: ok, np, just don't forget it. ;)

Comment: @KevinL can it also be rot13(Qe Wrxlyy) ? Honestly, that was the first thing that popped in my mind XD

Comment: I don't know who the hell that is :D @R.D

Comment: @R.D It could've been but not with this title :D Smash is really clearly pointing out to Hulk. And also "But I can actually be your savior" doesn't really fit for  rot13(qe wrxlyy naq ze ulqr)..